# Is it okay to slow cook sausage casserole without pan frying the sausages?

Tags: slow-cooking, sausages

We haven't got an oven/hob at the moment due to kitchen refurbishments and I'm currently slow cooking sausage casserole in a 2.5L slow cooker. There's about 6-8 thick sausages in there all cut up into quarters and mixed into the casserole.

It's been on high for around 5 hours now and I was wondering if the sausages would be edible? They're 97% pork Debbie & Andrews sausages (more info [HERE](http://www.debbieandandrews.co.uk/our-food/harrogate-pork-sausages))

Comment: Sliced then quartered? How thick are the slices? So each slice is like 4 pie pieces (like [this](http://ozlemsturkishtable.com/files/2013/01/563x421xbbbcjoqn.jpg.pagespeed.ic.9nDCnKWkPX.jpg))? Do you happen to have a thermometer? Have you seen any bubbling (like simmering)?

Comment: My gut says that you're fine as far as food safety, but that your final casserole might be a bit oily. If you could clarify a bit (as in answering questions in the above comment), I could probably be more helpful.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Just quartered, not sliced. Probably about an inch thick. Not sliced like a pie no, literally just got the sausage, chopped it in half, then chopped the halves in half.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no health issue here, the sausages will be cooked enough to be safe. The reason you fry off the sausages first is that you make the casings more edible, get flavor from maillard reactions and browning, and maybe get rid of some of the fat (if you discard the fat that comes out of the sausages that is).

I'm thinking that the sausage casings could end up being a bit soggy, however that depends on several factors and you'll probably get a good result. Worst case is you don't eat the sausage casings.

Comment: The casings will likely go soggy to the point of falling off, and the sausage will be very soft, but as you say, no safety problem.

Comment: I'd probably squeeze the sausage out of the casings before cooking if I was going to do this method. Heck, I'd still fry the meat off just for the flavor.

Comment: Just ate it. It was on high for just over 7 hours. The sausages were really soft and tasty, but as you say it would have tasted better probably had we fried them, we definitely will when our kitchen is back together! Thanks again.